# Can't enable FileVault with secure token

Tags: permission, encryption, filevault

I set up a new Mac Mini M1 (macOS 12.3 / build 21E230). The main user is non-admin, and the admin is a hidden account.

I can't enable FileVault. If I press the button, nothing happens. I tried to enable FileVault from the admin account; same issue.

The main user has a secure token:

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus
Secure token is ENABLED for user
```

If I try `fdesetup` instead:

```
admin@Kevins-Mac-mini kevinn % sudo fdesetup enable
Password:
Enter the user name:kevinn
Enter the password for user 'kevinn':
2022-03-22 09:37:42.225 fdesetup[] set accountPolicies error :Error Domain=com.apple.OpenDirectory Code=4001 "Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.}
Recovery key = ' '
```

Comment: I’d be curious which MDM profiles if any are installed and how the hidden  accounts were set up. There are a few wrinkles these can introduce…

Comment: I didn't used MDM on this device, the admin is hidden following the normal procedure https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998

Answer (score 2):

The `kevinn` user probably hasn't got a secure token. You can check if that is the case by running the following command in the Terminal:

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus kevinn
```

To add a secure token for the `kevinn` user, run the following command:

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenOn kevinn -password -
```

Comment: The user already have a securetoken though (admin@Kevins-Mac-mini kevinn % sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus kevinn
2022-03-22 11:56:12.038 sysadminctl[] Secure token is ENABLED for user Kevin

Comment: Okay - it was worth a shot - it is one of those things that can be the cause of not being able to enable FileVault on a new system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to login with the admin account and enable it from the Settings Menu, there will be a more detailed error message on what is the problem.

Comment: nothing happen at all, no error message or anything (from both standard user and admin user)

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Console.app when you try to enable FileVault?

Comment: I forgot about the console.app, to be honest I'm not an expert of MacOS logs, but if I filter "FileVault" there is no result

Comment: Do not filter for "FileVault" - that won't work.